# Using LinkedIn API to get list of profiles according to college

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, linkedin-api

Is there a way to use LinkedIn API tools to get a list of profiles of people who all went to the same university? I'm aware that this could be accomplished using a scraping script but I'm checking if there's an easier way of doing this. Preferred language would be python but I'm open to anything if it's possible.